# How can I use strace on a command executed as a specific, non-root user?

Tags: permissions, sudo, strace

I'm trying to use `strace` to observe where a certain process searches for files.  The locations this process searches will differ depending on the user and their unique environment variables.  However, `strace`requires root permission to run and when I run:

```
sudo strace mycommand
```

`mycommand` seems to execute in the context of the root user, and the searched locations are not applicable to the current user.

The following attempts to make mycommand execute in the context of user (named "user") were unsuccessful:

```
sudo strace su user -c "mycommand"

sudo strace su -u user mycommand
```

**How can I use `strace` on a command executed as a specific, non-root user?**

Comment: What system are you running on? I can run `strace` as an unprivileged user (on my own processes).

Comment: It's Debian, but with some modifications (not my own).  I guess one of the modifications must have been to lock down access to `strace`

Comment: this is not inside a container

Comment: I suspect that the problem is your process is missing the `cap_sys_ptrace` capability.  You can run `capsh --print | grep cap_sys_ptrace` to verify (if you get no output, then it's missing).

Comment: @AndyDalton that's not good advice. `strace` doesn't need any extra caps to trace your own processes, or the other people's processes when run as root. Dumping a privilege-escalating `./mytrace` somewhere means giving root to anybody able to run it.

Comment: Did you use `-f` as in `sudo strace -f su user -c "mycommand"` to have strace also trace the children? You could also temporarily open up the ptrace permissions with `sudo sysctl kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0`. Use `sysctl kernel.yama.ptrace_scope` to find the current value before this so you can restore it (unless it is 3, cannot change). See [Yama](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt).

Answer (score 4):

Without modifying strace/ptrace permissions.

`sudo strace -u someuser -E HOME=/home/someuser [any extra args] [traced command]`

Via https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html,

```
       -u username
       --user=username
              Run command with the user ID, group ID, and supplementary
              groups of username.  This option is only useful when
              running as root and enables the correct execution of
              setuid and/or setgid binaries.  Unless this option is used
              setuid and setgid programs are executed without effective
              privileges.
```

```
       -E var=val
       --env=var=val
              Run command with var=val in its list of environment
              variables.
```

Changing the `HOME` environment variable isn't strictly necessary, but the process I was trying to trace was getting denied trying to use `root`'s HOME.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set a no-root user followed by strace and command, like this:

```
sudo -u <no-root user> strace <command>
```

Ex:

```
sudo -u noroot strace ls
```

-u - Run command as user

Comment: That produces the following output: 
    ```strace: test_ptrace_get_syscall_info: PTRACE_TRACEME: Operation not permitted
strace: ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...): Operation not permitted```

Comment: it is not possible to run strace as root end de command as noroot, it's because the command is a parameter of strace.